# omniauth-google-oauth2 cause frozen at google allow access page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth

At the Rails 4 project, I use google oauth2 access in authentication. 
I use following gems.

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'cancan'
```

All do well in PC's browser. But when new user register with google at the mobile phone's browser, omniauth callback failure error is occured and frozen at google allow access page. If new user did registration at PC, mobile phone can login successfully. Just only faced with frozen error when new user register with mobile phone. I used both Android and IOS phone, but both face same error.

Comment: Unless you share the error message you received, I'm afraid there's nothing anyone can do for you.

Comment: Error cause at client. When I get, I will update post soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got error because of inactive services were included in omniauth scope.